# Passing and accessing object data outside table view

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to access object data that I used in my tableview method in my button action event, It is showing the error - "Use of undeclared identifier",
Here is my code snippets-

TableView method-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BlogTableViewCell";

    BlogTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
     long index1 = 2 * (indexPath.row);
    long index2 = index1 + 1;
    if (index1 < [self.BlogsArray count]) {
        cell.vw_blog1.tag = index1;
    BlogModel *blog = [self.BlogsArray objectAtIndex:index1];
        cell.lbl_blogTitle1.text = blog.blogTitle;
        cell.lbl_blogDescripton1.text = blog.blogDesc;
}
```

My button Action method -

```
- (IBAction)btnAction_AuthorName1:(id)sender {

      NSLog(@"Author1 of blog1 is clicked");
      UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Consult" bundle:nil];
      DRDetailsViewController *DRDetailVC = (DRDetailsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DRDetailsViewController"];
      DRDetailVC.DoctorID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",blog.userId];
      [APP_DELEGATE.navigationController pushViewController:DRDetailVC animated:YES];

}
```

It is showing error at blog.UserId .

Comment: Where is declared `blog.userId`? Where is declared `blog` in your method?

Comment: @Larme,blog is the the object of BlogModel and UserId is the key which I am accesing from another file.

Comment: button is inside your cell?

Comment: I want to use that blog object in my Button action

Comment: Could not find button which is associated with the action. If it is in cell, set it's tag to indexPath.row and access blog object from array in action using the tag of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `Tag` and create `Button` action in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BlogTableViewCell";

    BlogTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction_AuthorName1:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

You Button Action code.

```
- (IBAction)btnAction_AuthorName1:(UIButton *)sender {

    BlogModel *blog = [self.BlogsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

    NSLog(@"Author1 of blog1 is clicked");
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Consult" bundle:nil];
    DRDetailsViewController *DRDetailVC = (DRDetailsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DRDetailsViewController"];
    DRDetailVC.DoctorID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",blog.userId];
    [APP_DELEGATE.navigationController pushViewController:DRDetailVC animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: showing this - Property 'tag' not found on object of type '__strong id'

Comment: you have to set tag to `button` that you added in your `BlogTableViewCell` cell.

Comment: showing this error -Property 'btnAction_AuthorName2' not found on object of type 'BlogTableViewCell *'

Comment: @Sudhir, Okay, If this answer helps you then you can upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

Add Tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath method for your button.

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and then get the tag value for selected index

```
- (IBAction)btnAction_AuthorName1:(UIButton *)sender {

  BlogModel *blog = [self.BlogsArray objectAtIndex:sender.tag];

  NSLog(@"Author1 of blog1 is clicked");
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Consult" bundle:nil];
  DRDetailsViewController *DRDetailVC = (DRDetailsViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DRDetailsViewController"];
  DRDetailVC.DoctorID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",blog.userId];
  [APP_DELEGATE.navigationController pushViewController:DRDetailVC animated:YES];

}
```